# Algorithmically computing bounds on multiple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have been wrestling with the following problem for several reasons:

Integrate $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2\,}$ over the region $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$.
My first question was: How do I set up the integral?
This was answered really clearly and I understand the form of the triple integral in both cartesian and spherical coordinates. What concerns me the most now is how the integrating region is transformed from one set to another in a methodical fashion.

I know that because in this case, the integrating region is a sphere, then the bounds for the spherical coordinates are trivial to find. However, what if I had to integrate the same function over the region 
$$\{\ (x,y,z):\quad 0\le x\le 1,\quad -1/3 \le y \le \sqrt{1-x^2\,},\quad 0 \le z \le \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2\,}\ \}\ ?$$
That is just an example, my problem is not with spherical coordinates or with the integral at hand, but with the apparent over-reliance on intuition that will not be available to me if I ever have to deal with higher dimensions or regions that are not triangles or squares or spheres. Is there a method, no matter how tedious, that can be used to determine the region in the transformed space and therefore the new integral bounds?

Comment: When integrals and their regions get too complicated analytically then look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method

Comment: @arthur but that requires a computer. Is there really no method like finding intersections or substituting the variables or something methodical? What if I had to integrate a quadruple integral and I did not have a computer for the Monte Carlo Method? Does this mean that only integrals with nice regions (e.g. spheres, cylinders, planes, 3D surfaces) can get integrated and transformed analytically?

Comment: Guacho Perez : solving for one variable in terms of others to define the boundary can have multiple branches (e.g. $\pm \sqrt{f(x)} \,$ ) and stationary points need special treatment. For example see sections 3 and 4 in
http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2007-76-260/S0025-5718-07-01937-0/S0025-5718-07-01937-0.pdf .

Comment: Please excuse me if I am missing something, but couldn't you just use a triple integral with variable bounds, like $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\frac1 3}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dz dy dx$$? Once again, I'm not certain if this applies to your situation. Also, I don't know if this method will work with circular definitions of bounds. Related link: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TripleIntegrals.aspx

Comment: @algorithmsx I could use those bounds, it would be a tedious integral to work with but it is possible. I know that. My question is how to change the bounds after a change of variables. There may be regions that are too complicated to visualize, how do we deal with those?